# stacked JPanel repaint not correctly

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jpanel

I tried to make game with 2 panel stack each other, first panel is for canvas where all tiles and all game object is drawing on it and the second one is for the top layer frame where I have png image with transparency for the background and will contain `JTextBox`, `JTabbedPanel` and `JLabel`

My problems is when i repaint the canvas, part of the top frame becoming covered by a canvas.

Why is that? and also when i add `JButton` on canvas, the `JButton` is draw on top of my top frame panel.

**Edit:**

I have tried using JLayeredPane but still give me same result.

```
    // initComponent from MyGame
    private void initComponent() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("My Game");
        this.setSize(320, 240);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setResizable(false);

        JLayeredPane layered = this.getLayeredPane();
        layered.add(new Canvas(), 0);
        layered.add(new TopFrame(), 1);
    }
```

This top frame and my canvas:

[image]

What I get | what I want

[image]

**Main**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyGame extends JFrame {

    public MyGame() {
        this.initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("My Game");
        this.setSize(320, 240);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setResizable(false);

        this.add(new TopFrame());       
        this.add(new Canvas());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame game = new MyGame();
                game.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**TopFrame**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TopFrame extends JPanel {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 240;

    private BufferedImage bgImage;

    public TopFrame() {
        this.initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

        bgImage = new BufferedImage(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        try {
            bgImage = ImageIO.read(new File("FRAME.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

**Canvas**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 227;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 240;

    BufferedImage image;
    BufferedImage imgBuffer;
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public Canvas() {
        this.initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        this.setBounds(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        imgBuffer = new BufferedImage(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        g2d = imgBuffer.createGraphics();

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("tile.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawComponent();
                repaint();
            }
        }, 0, 100);
    }

    public void drawComponent() {
        /* will do tile drawing */
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(imgBuffer, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to get my canvas with all contained object drawn at the bottom?

Comment: Please don't add tags like _[SOLVED]_ in the title. Instead post an answer (like you did), and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solved]** using JLayeredPane and make TopFrame `setOpaque(false);`

I have wrong code when try using `JLayeredPane`.

My final code working code now:

**Main**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyGame extends JFrame {

    public MyGame() {
        this.initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("My Game");
        this.setSize(320, 240);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setResizable(false);

        JLayeredPane layered = this.getLayeredPane();
        layered.add(new Canvas(), new Integer(0));
        layered.add(new TopFrame(), new Integer(1));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame game = new MyGame();
                game.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**TopFrame**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TopFrame extends JPanel {
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 320;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 240;

    private BufferedImage bgImage;

    public TopFrame() {
        this.initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBounds(0, 0, FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.setOpaque(false);

        bgImage = new BufferedImage(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        try {
            bgImage = ImageIO.read(new File("FRAME.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

**Canvas**

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends JPanel {
    private static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = 227;
    private static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = 240;

    BufferedImage image;
    BufferedImage imgBuffer;
    Graphics2D g2d;

    public Canvas() {
        this.initComponent();
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        this.setBounds(0, 0, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        imgBuffer = new BufferedImage(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR_PRE);
        g2d = imgBuffer.createGraphics();

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("tile.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                drawComponent();
                repaint();
            }
        }, 0, 100);
    }

    public void drawComponent() {
        /* will do tile drawing */
        g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(imgBuffer, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```